# c++ шаблоны класса с enable_if не компилируются

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++, метапрограммирование

Всем привет! У меня возник такой вопрос: почему компилятор жалуется на темплейты класса?
У меня есть 2 варианта одного и того же класса, один из них должен создаваться когда используется нетривиальное копирование типа, другой когда тривиальное. (т.е. в программе должны/могут быть созданы одновременно и тот и другой)

```
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<!(std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value), std::nullptr_t> = nullptr>
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<(std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value), std::nullptr_t> = nullptr>
```

Но почему-то компилятор жалуется:

```
error: template parameter 'typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_trivially_copyable<_Tp>::value), std::nullptr_t>::type <anonymous>'
error: redeclared here as 'typename std::enable_if<std::is_trivially_copyable<_Tp>::value, std::nullptr_t>::type <anonymous>'
```

В чем может быть проблема? Половину гугла пролистал и нашел только примеры, когда enable_if используется для разных проверок, но не для проверки двух противоположностей.

Comment: Для шаблонных классов нет overload resolution, поэтому SFINAE не будет работать. Сделайте частичную специализацию — https://godbolt.org/z/sKEP6vrar.

Comment: @tocic спасибо! Получается enable_if при "перегрузке" классов неприменим/не нужен?

Comment: Можно и `std::enable_if` использовать, если он в специализации, — https://godbolt.org/z/n8n8G9Yoh. Ещё посмотрите на https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t.